# Sharing code between Play and Console app in scala

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

I am looking to share a common module between a Play app in scala and a scala console app. My directory structure looks like this:

```
RootFolder
-- consoleApp
   src/main/scala: MyApp.scala

-- playApp
   app/controllers: MyController.scala

-- common
   src/main/scala: MyLib.scala

-- project
     Build.scala
     plugins.sbt
```

The following is my Build.scala, and it works for glueing the common module and the play app.

```
object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

  val appName         = "helloworld"
  val appVersion      = "1.0"

  val appDependencies = Seq(
    // Add your project dependencies here,
  )

  val common = Project("common", file("common"))

  val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies, path=file("playApp")).settings(
    // Add your own project settings here
  ).dependsOn(common)

}
```

How would I combine the console app with common?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually do the same thing with your console project. The syntax varies a bit, [here's the documentation for 0.13.2](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.2/docs/Getting-Started/Multi-Project.html#classpath-dependencies).

```
lazy val console = Project("console", file("consoleApp")).dependsOn("common")
```